# Swift: open calendar to a specific date

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

I use the following code to open calendar to a specific date (2018/01/12):

```
    var userCalendar = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = DateComponents.init()
    dateComponents.year = 2018
    dateComponents.month = 1
    dateComponents.day = 12
    let customDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)
    let interval = (customDate?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)!
    if let url = URL(string: "calshow:\(interval)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Such code seems to work. The main problem is that if you launch it for the first time, the calendar would automatically jump to the current date. Only when you run it for the second time will the calendar jump to the specified date. Why so?

Comment: try setting the date in viewWillAppear method instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: I've got the same problem here. Looks like a bug on Apple's calendar app.

Comment: Reported to Apple, here is the open radar link https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4936646961135616